# how to clear woocommerce checkout fields after place order?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How do I clear chekcout fields in woocommerce after placing an order, so that when the registered customer makes his/her next order, he/she has to fill the fields again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just need to add this single line in your child theme's functions.php

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_get_value','__return_empty_string',10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [woocommerce_checkout_get_value](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_checkout_get_value/) filter to clear the fields, but this will clear them each time the page is loaded.

```
function clear_checkout_fields($input){
    return '';
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_get_value' , 'clear_checkout_fields' );
```